# How to display timezones abbreviations?

Tags: timezone

I'm looking at the timezones and trying to figure out abbreviations. I'm using list of timezones and offsets to display them on my website.

Client asked to add abbreviation for each timezone. Once I listed abbreviations I realised that there are the same timezone names for different abbreviations such as:

```
'edt'
  'offset' = -14400
  'timezone_id' = 'America/New_York'

'ept' 
  'offset' = -14400
  'timezone_id' = 'America/New_York'

'est'
  'offset' = -18000
  'timezone_id' = 'America/New_York'

'ewt' 
  'offset' = -14400
  'timezone_id' = 'America/New_York'
```

Can someone please explain what is that exactly and how do I know which abbreviation to display?

Comment: maybe you can just extract them from [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)

Comment: Hi. Please elaborate on your use cases. What language/platform are you using? Where does the data you showed here come from? Are you starting from the abbreviation and trying to resolve a time zone ID? Or do you have a time zone ID and need an abbreviation? Something else? Is *any* abbreviation acceptable, or are you looking for those from a specific list?  Are you always using *English*?  Are you prepared for time zones that don't have *any* abbreviation? Is there a specific timestamp involved, or is it shown in a list of time zones? Are you just dealing with the US, or is this worldwide?

Comment: I'm using PHP for this

 Are you starting from the abbreviation..? I'm looping through that data above and trying to get the right abbreviation for timeyone
 
 Is any abbreviation acceptable...? Honestly I'm not sure, I'm trying to get the right abbreviation, for America/New_York it would be EST

  Are you always using English? Yes

  Are you prepared for time zones that don't have any abbreviation? Nop, I think all timezines have abbreviations

  Is there a specific timestamp involved, ...? I'm just showing a list of timezones

   Are you just dealing with the US...? Worldwide

Answer (score 1):

[US Timezones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCoU5.png)

If you're working with US Timezones they are broken down into 4 Timezones that cover the Mainland US (Except Alaska and Hawaii)

EST EASTERN STANDARD TIME   UTC - 5

EDT EASTERN DAYLIGHT TIME   UTC - 4

CST CENTRAL STANDARD TIME   UTC - 6

CDT CENTRAL DAYLIGHT TIME   UTC - 5

MST MOUNTAIN STANDARD TIME  UTC - 7

MDT MOUNTAIN DAYLIGHT TIME  UTC - 6

PST PACIFIC STANDARD TIME   UTC - 8

PDT PACIFIC DAYLIGHT TIME   UTC - 7

So you'd be using EST,CST,MST and PST for the Mainland US anyway. Hawaii and Alaska have different Timezones and off the top of my head am not sure exactly what they are

Comment: Meant to clarify for the ones you've displayed there only EST applies

Comment: Thanks. What about other abbreviations where America/New_York appears?
I'm displaying all Earth's timezone, New York was just an example of timezone which is appearing for different abbreviations

Comment: @FosAvance maybe the dataset you're using isn't the best https://github.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json/blob/master/timezones.json 
That link contains all the valid timezones across the world with there UTC offsets in them + abbreviations

Comment: I'm using PHP's official library for that

Comment: @KodeyThomas - Hi, and thanks for answering! :) What you said isn't inaccurate, but it doesn't really address the question. Though it's currently unclear what is actually being asked for, it would be better to ask for clarification in the question comments before providing a partial answer. Please read [*How do I write a good answer?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), especially the section titled *"Answer well-asked questions"*.  Thanks.

Comment: To answer your other points, Most of Alaska uses `AKST`/`AKDT` (UTC-9/-8), but the Aleutian Islands are another hour offset and use `HAST`/`HADT` (UTC-10/-9) because the official time zone name is "Hawaii-Aleutian Time".  Hawaii also uses `HAST` (UTC-10), but never `HADT` because there is no DST there.  Some Hawaiians just use `HST`, without regard for the Aleutian islands since they are so far North.  Also, keep in mind that "CST" is highly ambiguous outside the US.  The asker's profile indicates they are in Croatia, so likely they are looking for worldwide time zones.